# Set header-width of CTabItem

Tags: swt, ctabitem

Can the width of the tab-header of a CTabItem be set arbitrary?

Thnx in advance!

Kind regard,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you **can't** do that. Not at least by any exposed API (read `public methods`). 
A possible solution is to extend the code of `CTabFolder` and `CTabItem`.

Comment: that's what I found out so far, too 8/

Answer (score 2):

You can try to override CTabItem, but this solution doesn't look as nice solution (nevertheless I use it):

```
CTabItem tabItem;

final int tabWidth = 90;

tabItem = new CTabItem( tabFolder, SWT.NONE ) {
    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds( ) {
        Rectangle bounds = super.getBounds();
        bounds.x = 0 * tabWidth;
        bounds.width = tabWidth;
        return bounds;
    }
};
tabItem.setText( __lang.str( this, "Tab Item I" ) );

tabItem = new CTabItem( tabFolder, SWT.NONE ) {
    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds( ) {
        Rectangle bounds = super.getBounds();
        bounds.x = 1 * tabWidth;
        bounds.width = tabWidth;
        return bounds;
    }
};
tabItem.setText( __lang.str( this, "Tab Item II" ) );

tabItem = new CTabItem( tabFolder, SWT.NONE ) {
    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds( ) {
        Rectangle bounds = super.getBounds();
        bounds.x = 2 * tabWidth;
        bounds.width = tabWidth;
        return bounds;
    }
};
tabItem.setText( __lang.str( this, "Tab Item III" ) );
```

Comment: I like this. I also used `tabFolder.indexOf(this)` inside the `getBounds()` method to get the correct x offset.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can pad the title with extra spaces
using `String.format` like:

```
cTabItem.setText(String.format("%-15s", orgTitle));
```

This will add extra spaces to the end of the string if its length is less than 15 characters.

Check this for more details:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html